# Unable to load jupyter notebook on browser after installing a letsencrypt SSL certificate for my domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter notebook (running on AWS EC2 instance) was working well (on port 8888) after following the steps mentioned [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server).

But then I decided to get a proper domain name from NameCheap in order to get the letsencrypt SSL certificate. After installing the certificate by following steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04), I changed the jupyter config file with new locations for certificate and key. Once I did that, I am unable to load the jupyter notebook in the web browser.

There are no SSL or any other kind of errors from Jupyter after executing `jupyter notebook` (on Ubuntu 18.04 bash). The browser simply cannot connect to mydomain.com:8888 (https). It happily connects to mydomain.com (https). The only difference between working and not working state is that I got a proper domain name along with SSL certificates for that.

Any help is appreciated. Happy to expand more if the above information is insufficient.

Comment: Generally notebooks or any similar apps like this which are not meant too be publicly available (i.e. only you are using it) are securrly accessed over ssh tunnels. This avoids all the problems with domians, ssl certs and so on.

Comment: yes but I need it to be publicly available in order to show the results inside an iframe